# Manually uninstall old version of glib

Tags: homebrew, glib

I try to build gst-plugins-base on macOS 12.5. I get this error on meson.

> Dependency glib-2.0 found: NO found 2.36.0 but need: '>= 2.56.0'

I tried reinstall glib by "brew reinstall glib". Then "brew list glib --version" shows "glib 2.72.3"
But meson still find older version of glib.

I guess older version of glib is installed on somewhere in my storage.
Is that possible to uninstall old version of glib manually?
Anyone know how meson check version of glib?

Comment: Meson probably tries to look into `/usr/local/lib/` directory for `libglib-2.0.so.*`, so check out what's there.

Answer (score 0):

*gtester* is an executable file which shows glib version.

"gtester --version" shows current glib version.

I found 2 *gtester* is exists on my storage.
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.72.3/bin and /usr/local/bin.

I want glib(2.72.3), run this command.

> export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.72.3/bin:$PATH"

After this modification of PATH, meson is worked.

Answer (score 0):

I need to copy latest glib-2.0.pc on /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
Or make symbolic link.

Other glib modules .pc files also, gio-2.0.pc, gio-unix-2.0.pc, gobject-2.0.pc, gmodule-2.0.pc,

meson look up pkgconfig dir first.